# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'numberToTest' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Tags: php

I am trying to make a for loop that will give me the integers 1 to 1000. i have gotten this error message and cant find out what i did wrong. i looked threw people who got the same message but could not find a helpful answer that fit my need. the full error message was

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'numberToTest' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in C:\xampp\htdocs\prime2\primeNumberFinder.php on line 15

here is the code:

```
<?php


class primeNumber{

function numberToTest(){

for($i=0; $i<1000; ++$i){

echo "$i<br>";
}

}

numberToTest();
}
?>
```

thanks!

Comment: Missing `}` to close the class definition; spurious `}` after the function call; and treating a class method as a normal global function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the class with a `}` ***before*** trying to call its methods

You also need to call the class method correctly, as a method of an instantiated class

```
<?php

class primeNumber{

    public function numberToTest(){
        for($i=0; $i<1000; ++$i){
            echo "$i<br>";
         }
    }
}

// Create an instance of the class as $x
$x = new primeNumber();
// Call the numberToTest() method of your instantiated class
$x->numberToTest();
```

Comment: Also right now your look only goes to 999 to make it go to 1000 as make your loop statement `for($i=0; $i<=1000; ++$i)`

Comment: @Dish_Rex - I'm trying to answer the syntax error problem, not spoonfeed a prime number testing class for the OP

Comment: @MarkBaker I think some reference to basic OOP for OP would be helpful. (e.g. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php , http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

Comment: Doesn't he also need a scope on his function declaration? I.e. "public function numberToTest()"

Comment: @JamesSpence - it should be declared, yes; though it will default to public

Comment: Understood @MarkBaker, sorry. JamesSpence if a method's visibility  is not explicitly declared it's visibility will be public, but I think this is beside the point as well.